# How to filter by one column, and sort by another, using an index, in a query with a limit clause

Tags: query-performance, mariadb

Suppose I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INT,
    num_comments INT,
    created_at DATETIME,

    /* Irrelevant fields omitted. */

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX (created_at),
    INDEX (num_comments)
);
```

And I want to run the following query on this table, to get the top 100 posts ordered by the number of comments, posted within the last 30 days. And also suppose that this table is huge, and that within the last 30 days there are hundreds of thousands of posts.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created_at > '2023-02-11' ORDER BY num_comments LIMIT 100;
```

Currently there's no index on this table that could help this query return the results only using an index. Right now, the database has to first get all the posts within the last 30 days (again, hundreds of thousands of rows), and only then can it rank order them, to get the top 100.

How can I create an index on this table so that the above query could be run in under, say, 10 milliseconds or so (that is, using only an index, without any table scans or temp tables)? Is it even possible? Do I have to maybe create another table entirely (a `posts_in_last_30_days` for example)?

Comment: Okay, thanks. Just did.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create an index on this table so that the above query could be run in under, say, 10 milliseconds or so (that is, using only an index, without any table scans or temp tables)? Is it even possible?

Yes, it's possible to create a performant index  for your query via a [composite index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/compound-composite-indexes/).

That index should lead with the field(s) you're filtering on, then follow with the fields you're ordering by, being defined like so: `(created_at, num_comments)`.

> Do I have to maybe create another table entirely (a posts_in_last_30_days for example)?

No, that would be a pain to manage.

Comment: My understanding is that composite indexes are created by concatenating the values that make up the composite key. So, in the `(created_at, num_comments)` index, the high-order bits of the index values (of the B-tree) will contain the value of `created_at`; and in the low-order bits the value of `num_comments`. So, in this case, the rows of the index would be ordered by `created_at` first, and only then by `num_comments`.

Comment: Suppose that the `WHERE created_at > '2023-02-11'` part of the query matches a million rows. Those million rows, per my understanding, are not ordered by `num_comments` in this index. So, the DB has to go through all the million rows to select the top 100.

Comment: @JonathanWilson - True, "all million rows".  For _each_ day, they are ordered by `num_comments`.  But this does not help.  That gives you 30 lists to merge together, re-sort, and copy 100 out of.  MariaDB has not implemented that complexity because it is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. `>` and `ORDER` are two "range" thingies. Indexes are one-dimensional. Furthermore, saying `SELECT *` probably makes it impossible to have a "covering" index.

This reformulation may help:

```
SELECT  p2.*
    FROM (
        SELECT  id
            FROM  posts
            WHERE  created_at > '2023-02-11'
            ORDER BY  num_comments
            LIMIT  100 
         ) AS p1
    JOIN  posts AS p2 USING(id)
    ORDER BY  p2.num_comments;
```

And have these index on `posts`:

```
INDEX(num_comments, created_at, id),
INDEX(created_at, num_comments, id)
```

Why this helps...

- The inner query will use a "covering" index.  (The Optimizer will pick between those two covering indexes based on the distribution of data.)
- The result of the inner query is only 100 'rows'.
- The outer query then shovels the rest of the columns (`*`) around and sorts (again -- but only 100 row's worth).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, to be clear, the reason why this query is better than the `SELECT *` one is that since a covering index can be used in the inner query, the DB doesn't have to do any mapping between the index and the table rows, correct?

Comment: @JonathanWilson - Correct.  The entire _inner_ query is performed in the `INDEX's` BTree, without reaching over (via the `PRIMARY KEY` to get more columns from the data's BTree.  The _outer_ query needs to do 100 lookups. not "hundreds of thousands".  Even if a lot of the index needs to be scanned, it is probably smaller than the data.

Answer (score 0):

Possible, by cheating.

Using indices to skip sorts on large data volumes is very advantageous especially when LIMIT is used.

An index on (A,B) stores references to rows ordered by (A,B), therefore it can be used to skip the sort for `WHERE A=constant ORDER BY B`. The database simply starts reading the index at (A, lowest value of B) and reads it in order. The rows come out of the index in (A,B) order, but A is constant, so it is the same as ordering by B.

Note: I think you have to write `WHERE A=constant ORDER BY A,B` or `WHERE A=constant ORDER BY A DESC,B DESC` to trigger this optimization. It depends on the database and version.

This index cannot be used to skip the sort for `WHERE A>constant ORDER BY B`. In this case, several values of A will satisfy the condition. So the rows still come out of the index in (A,B) order, but this is no longer the same as ordering by B.

In order to cheat we must make A constant. The trick is simple: slice it by week.

If you take the top 100 most commented posts from the current week, and also from the 4 weeks before, for a total of 5 weeks... then you get 500 rows. If you then sort them by num_comments and apply LIMIT again, the result is the top 100 most commented posts in that time period. There's still a sort, but it's only 500 rows, so it's much faster than sorting all the posts as your current query does.

Implementation:

Add a date column to your table, say "created_week" which is equal to... `DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(created_at)) DAY)`, that's the [monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944055/how-do-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-mysql) of the week when the post was created. You can use a [generated column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) so it is set to the correct value without any extra effort, preferably a virtual one to avoid a costly ALTER TABLE.

Create an index on `(created_week DESC, num_comments DESC)`.

Now you can use `WHERE created_week=constant ORDER BY created_week DESC, num_comments DESC LIMIT 100` and you will get the top 100 most commented posts in that week. It uses the index instead of sorting so it should be very fast.

Then use this to get the top posts in the current week and 4 weeks before. This can either be built with as a string of UNION ALL with one subquery per week, or you can use a LATERAL JOIN like in this [similar query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/337594/finding-files-a-user-has-access-to-is-slow-when-ordering/337612#337612).

If you absolutely want the last 30 days, you can add "WHERE created_at>..." in the subquery for the oldest week. In this case I'd recommend adding the column to the index to make it covering.

If your posts contain long texts columns and you will only display a header in your top 100 posts list, it would be a good idea to use SUBSTRING() in your select to clip the length of that text column, so it does not bloat your sort. Likewise, only select necessary columns. Or, going all the way, only keep the id and join back to the posts table as the other answer suggests.

---

Another option, if you do this query very often, is to simply cache the results in a table. The cache can be updated at the beginning of each day. It should only contain the post ids, and an order number, then you can get the full results with a JOIN, to avoid having to update the number of comments in the cache.

If you want to have it in real time, you can invalidate and rebuild your cache when a post changes position in the order. So when a comment is added to a post: if its num_comments is lower than the num_comments of the last post in the cache, don't update. Then check if the new comment will cause cached posts to change order. If that is the case, update the cache.

This is a bit headache inducing ; the slicing solution should be fast enough to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought of a similar trick, but yours is definitely better. My one was simply adding a `is_this_month (bool)` column; which will be set to true by default, with a cron-job running at some regular interval to set it to false on all posts that are older.

One downside of your trick is that if I need to get the posts ordered by `num_comments` in the last year, then the DB will have to merge 365 separate result sets.

Comment: Indeed, slices should not be too thin: with weeks that would be 52 slices per year, it's already a lot. I think your idea would work well too if you don't mind the extra updates and alter table. In this case you could add an "age int" column instead of a bool, value 0 if last 30 days, value 1 if last year, 2 if older (or something of the sort) then index on (age desc, num_comments desc) so it can get top posts both in last 30 days and last year (the latter requiring one union all)